# unexpected token < in json with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using json and jquery to recieve asynchronous data in php application. But I found the Syntax Error of:

> Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected Token <

Please suggest me.
I used same code in another program which executed well but the below code shows error

HTML CODE/ Jquery Code:

```
$('#cmb_package').bind('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var destination = $("#destination").val();
    var service_val = $("#serviceid").val();
    var newdiv = $('#divserviceprovider');
    if (value == "NoPackage") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../costsheets/getpricebyajax',
            dataType: 'json',
            content: 'application/json',
            data: {
                service: service_val,
                destno: destination
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                newdiv.text('');
                newdiv.append(data.msg);
                newdiv.show(500);
                if (data.error === true) newdiv.show(500);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("fail " + errorThrown);
                newdiv.removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                newdiv.show(500);
            }
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#div-packagetype').show();
    }
});
```

PHP CODE:

```
function getpricebyajax()
{

            $str="";$substr="";
            header("Content-type: application/json");

            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = "Success";

            echo json_encode($return);

            exit;
     }
```

I am using cakephp 1.3 framework.

Comment: what is the actual json returned?

Comment: Which line of code triggers the error? What does your browser's development tools Net tab say about the request? Is the request successful? Does the response look like you expect?

Comment: @AmitJha - Your comment doesn't add new info, nor provide the requested details. Beside "Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected Token <" you should see a file name and line number, please check and add them to the question. Additionally, check whether the returned JSON is valid—ask for help if you don't know how.

Comment: try setting full url like `../costsheets/getpricebyajax.php`

Comment: Are your `<script>` tags properly closed?

Comment: It looks like your PHP script produces an error and the javascript trys to parse it. Can you write down the actual answer from the PHP script?

Comment: @Johni is right, I've had this problem before, it'll be down to your php producing some sort of exception and then jquery trying to parse the exception as JSON

Comment: As you are using a framework (cake PHP) may be your code is embeded into another process that will print the classic begin of a HTML page (like <html>...) ..?

Comment: Take a look at this page for example : http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/json-output-with-cakephp/ The user set a specific layout to let the result page (skeleton) blank : `$this->layout = 'ajax';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a framework (cake PHP) may be your code is embeded into another process that will print the classic begin of a HTML page (like `<html>`...etc)

Take a look at this page for example : [json output with CakePHP](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/json-output-with-cakephp/) The user set a specific layout to let the result page (skeleton) blank :

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```